# Am I violating LSP if the condition can be checked?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, solid

This base class for some shapes I have in my game looks like this. Some of the shapes can be resized, some of them can not.

```
   private Shape shape;

    public virtual void SetSizeOfShape(int x, int y)
    {
        if (CanResize()){
            shape.Width = x;
            shape.Height = y;
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("You cannot resize this shape");
        }

    }
    public virtual bool CanResize()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

In a sub class of a shape that I don't ever want to resize I am overriding the `CanResize()` method so a piece of client code can check before calling the `SetSizeOfShape()` method.

```
    public override bool CanResize()
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Here's how it might look in my client code:

```
    public void DoSomething(Shape s)
    {
        if(s.CanResize()){
            s.SetSizeOfShape(50, 70);
        }
    }
```

Is this violating LSP?

Comment: You're not violating LSP if you specify that shapes may or may not be resizable but that's a pretty smelly design.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290834/liskov-substitution-principle-and-streams has decent answers to almost exactly the same issue.

Comment: Instead of having a `canResize` method that could be skipped or implemented incorrectly, have an interface `Resizable` that provides `setSizeOfShape` and when needed, classes can accept a `Resizable` instead of a `Shape`, or perhaps they can accept a `ResizableShape` (`class ResizableShape implements Shape, Resizable`). This takes the burden of doing the right thing away from the programmer and instead lets the compiler enforce correct behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a nutshell, the Liskov Substitution Principle states that, given a number of objects that conform to a particular interface, you should be able to *swap them without causing errors in your program.*

If you can do that, then your classes don't violate LSP.

The [example provided in the LSP article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle#A_typical_violation) is quite illuminating.  It says:

> A typical example that violates LSP is a Square class that derives
> from a Rectangle class, assuming getter and setter methods exist for
> both width and height. The Square class always assumes that the width
> is equal with the height. If a Square object is used in a context
> where a Rectangle is expected, unexpected behavior may occur because
> the dimensions of a Square cannot (or rather should not) be modified
> independently.
>
> This problem cannot be easily fixed: if we can modify
> the setter methods in the Square class so that they preserve the
> Square invariant (i.e., keep the dimensions equal), then these methods
> will weaken (violate) the postconditions for the Rectangle setters,
> which state that dimensions can be modified independently.
>
> Violations
> of LSP, like this one, may or may not be a problem in practice,
> depending on the postconditions or invariants that are actually
> expected by the code that uses classes violating LSP.
> Mutability is a
> key issue here. If Square and Rectangle had only getter methods (i.e.,
> they were immutable objects), then no violation of LSP could occur.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still think what constitutes as an 'error' is often difficult to identify. Obviously throwing an exception is blatant and of course everyone knows the basic principles of shapes. But a more complex system it seems a lot more difficult to detect such violations.

Comment: It's worth noting that LSP is a direct result of Design by Contract.  If you're not designing by contract, using preconditions, postconditions and invariants, it's going to be hard to see the LSP violations.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's still substitutable, because you have the same pre-condition of requiring `CanResize` to be true for every class.  The problem is you are not letting the type system help you enforce that condition at compile time, and you are forcing unresizable shapes to worry about resizing APIs, which is an interface segregation violation.

Creating a separate interface for resizable shapes feels like more work now, but it will make it easier to work with in the long run, because it enables you to eliminate `if (CanResize()) ... else ...` code all over the place.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how it will reduce me checking for `if (canResize())`?

Comment: So something like an interface `ICanResize` and `ICannotResize` both do their appropriate action in terms of resizing and my shape base is not longer responsible for providing a resize abstraction.

Comment: Kind of, except you probably don't need an `ICannotResize`.  It's tough to explain without looking at the code that *calls* `SetSizeOfShape`.  Basically, code in that path should only deal with `IResizable` objects and shouldn't care that those objects happen to also be `Shape`s.

Comment: A problem with defining separate interfaces is that it becomes much more difficult to wrap or aggregate things. For example, consider a method which is supposed to accept two instances of `Iterable<T>` and return an `Iterable<T>` that contains all the items in one followed by all the items in the other. Suppose such a method is given a 1,000,000-item `List<Foo>` and an `Iterable<Foo>` that doesn't support anything other than basic iteration, and code which receives the return from the method wants items at indices 1,000,001 and 1,000,002.

Comment: Having the return from the aggregating method only return `Iterable<T>` would make it impossible to retrieve indices 1,000,001 and 1,000,002 without having to iterate through the million-item list.  On the other hand, if it could expose a better interface to the caller, then it could expedite the parts of the operation that could be expedited.

Answer (score 0):

I think that including the "canResize" you are not violating LSP because your client code works with concrete implementations that can be resized and with implementations that cannot be resized. You can switch different implementations without problem.

Another option to implement something like that is returning or not an object to perform the resizing using the maybe monad:

```
shape.getResizor().IfNotNull(resizor => ...)
```

This its better to document your API and say "remember call first to canResize".